# VIM: find empty lines and print them with 1,2,3 lines after and before

Tags: vim

I can find empty lines doing this command :g/^$. How to extend this command to print 1 line (2 lines, etc.) before exact empty line and after?

Comment: what do you mean "print"?

Answer (score 4):

```
:g/^$/.,+2p
```

will print every empty line and the two lines below. Use `:#` instead of `:p` if you also want the line numbers.

Note that this won't work if the matched line is the last.

See `:help :p`, `:help :#`, and `:help :range`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *relative addressing*, and then issue two `:print` commands, one for the line before, one for the line after the empty one:

```
:g/^$/-1print|+2print
```

This also scales to multiple lines; here two:

```
:g/^$/-2,-1print|+2,+3print
```

This may give `E16: Invalid range` at the beginning or end. You can suppress those errors via `:silent! unsilent ...`:

```
:g/^$/silent! unsilent -2,-1print|silent! unsilent +2,+3print
```